# WordPress Custom Fonts Problem!

Tags: uploads, css, child-theme

I added custom fonts on my website! Its based on Genesis Framework.More then 15 days web fonts show every where,suddenly fonts missing but i checkout my fonts link and fonts deceleration on CSS its okay!

`@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamRounded-Bold';
  src: url('mountnow.com/wp-content/themes/centric-pro/fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('http://mountnow.com/wp-content/themes/centric-pro/fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.otf')  format('opentype'),
         url('http://mountnow.com/wp-content/themes/centric-pro/fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('http://mountnow.com/wp-content/themes/centric-pro/fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('http://mountnow.com/wp-content/themes/centric-pro/fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.svg#GothamRounded-Bold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style:normal;
}`

I don't Know Why its happen?[image: Google Chrome Inspect elements screenshot]

Comment: Can you explain in the question how/where you have added fonts to your child theme?

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I added fonts on fonts folder and link up it from child themes style.css file. MY web page is http://www.mountnow.com

Comment: Please show this code in the question above.

Comment: A note to the wise: own your fonts by license and include any stipulation it requires for use. Font faces are similar to images and can be easily denied with copyright via terms of service at your hosting company.

Comment: Your font is working for me.

Comment: Hello Nathan ! here  is a Screenshot!https://redpen.io/vyf3bce966c599ed4d

Comment: But it do not show from my office MAC, browser firefox and same time from my home same browser!!!!

Comment: I can't help you without seeing code. Code. Put code in question. Edit question, put code.

Comment: Do you get my screenshot?

Comment: Is it works for you?

Comment: Put the code in your question.

Comment: Okay checkout from here https://gist.github.com/momin-ctg/46cac463e03cc637a04a3dfa973fcbc4

Comment: No. This question is probably going to be deleted.

Comment: Hello Nathan! i added code formats on Question!

Comment: @NathanPowell comment feeds like this is where programming memes are born. Thanks for brightening up my day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In */wp-content/themes/centric-pro/style.css*, delete *line 88* through line *113* this removes all the font-face declarations.

On *line 88* paste the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamRounded-Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.otf') format('opentype'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), 
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Bold.svg#GothamRounded-Bold') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamRounded-Light';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/GothamRounded-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Light.otf') format('opentype'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Light.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Light.svg#GothamRounded-Light') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamRounded-Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.otf')  format('opentype'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/GothamRounded-Medium.svg#GothamRounded-Medium') format('svg');
}
```

#### Treat font-face as case sensitive

In */wp-content/themes/centric-pro/custom.css* on *line 5* change:

```
font-family: "Gothamrounded-medium";
```

to

```
font-family: "GothamRounded-Medium";
```

Comment: Okay ! I am going in to change..